# Memory Leak when using TBXML textFromElement

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am receiving memory leaks from my methods using [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) to parse an XML file.

It is giving me NSCFString 'Leaked Objects' with. When I look at the stack trace, its last call is using the TBXML method textForElement; used to obtain the string in the element.

If I click on the trace it brings me to this method from a TBXML class file:

```
+ (NSString*) textForElement:(TBXMLElement*)aXMLElement {
    if (nil == aXMLElement->text) 
        return @"";
    return [NSString stringWithCString:&aXMLElement->text[0] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here is one of the methods using textForElement:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)parseNewsXML
{

NSString *newsURL = @"http://www.millersville.edu/news/rss.php";

NSMutableArray *newsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

EventArticleObject *currentArticle = [[EventArticleObject alloc] init];


tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newsURL]];
rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

if(rootXMLElement)
{
    node_channel = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"channel" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

    if(node_channel)
    {
        node_item = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:node_channel];

        while(node_item)
        {
            node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:node_item];
            NSString *title = [TBXML textForElement:node_traverse];
            title = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];


            [currentArticle setTitle:title];
            node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"link" parentElement:node_item];
            NSString *link = [TBXML textForElement:node_traverse];
            [currentArticle setLink:link];
            [currentArticle setDate:nil];

            [newsArray addObject:currentArticle];
            node_item = node_item -> nextSibling;
        }
    }
}
[currentArticle release];
return newsArray;
}
```

Here is a second method also receiving the same leaks:

```
- (void)parseMuAlertXML
{

time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.millersville.edu/alert/alert.xml"];

tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithURL:url];
rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

if(rootXMLElement)
{
    node_alert = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"alert" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

    if(node_alert)
    {
        node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"startdate" parentElement:node_alert];
        NSInteger startString =  [[TBXML textForElement:node_traverse] intValue];
        time_t startTime = startString;

        node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"enddate" parentElement:node_alert];
        NSInteger endString =  [[TBXML textForElement:node_traverse] intValue];
        time_t endTime = endString;

        node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"type" parentElement:node_alert];
        alertType = [[TBXML textForElement:node_traverse] retain];

        node_message = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"message" parentElement:node_alert];

        if(node_message)
        {
            node_traverse = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"p" parentElement:node_message];
            alertMessage = [TBXML textForElement:node_traverse];
            alertMessage = [[alertMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#160;" withString:@" "] retain];
        }

        if((unixTime >= startTime) && (unixTime <= endTime))
        {
            [alertButton setHidden:NO];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
        } else {
            [alertButton setHidden:YES];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone see whats going on wrong in there? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocated **newsArray** and returned it in the function. Are you releasing it later on, where you are using it?

The tool seems not to be understanding this. It thinks you allocated and are not releasing it.

Ideally, you should autorelease objects that you need to return from functions.

Comment: I added the other method where I am receiving the same leaks, and I am not returning anything. At first the other method did not return anything either but still was leaking.

Comment: I was referring to parseNewsXML function. There you are returning newsArray that you have allocated. No idea when and where are you releasing it. Try having it autorelease and check for leaks again. Leak in TBXML class file indicates leak in their API.

Comment: I am handling newsArray and that is not leaking; it must be something with the library. It's weird though because I am parsing a few other documents that aren't giving me any problems when using textForElement..

Comment: I don't think it is the parser, I have discovered whats going on. I looked in the Stack Trace again at the leaks, and 'title' and 'link' are being leaked. They are created, then given the textForElement value, then being set to the tempArticle's title and link, which is retaining those strings. I am just unsure how to handle this, any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your currentArticle setter is probably it.

You should use the @synthesizer to make this a bit easier, otherwise ensure to make a copy of the string, release the old one, and have current Article handle the memory. If you do this:

```
@implementation CurrentArticle

- (void) setLink:(NSString*)value;
{
     link = value; //You will either get a pointer to a value that belongs in another class, like pointing to an array instead of copying it, and changing the value, you'll be like "Why did it change?"

///////////// OR THIS:
      if(link) {
    [link release];
    } 
    link = [value copy];
    [value release];
}
```

The synthesizer handles this, probably way more elegant.

But yeah, I don't see where your problem is inside the above code, it appears to be autoreleased values the entire way.

And yes, I know this is old, but that's where I would look, and I'm sure other people will look for reminders on those string pointers. We get spoiled by having too many constants and shortcuts, but @"String" is a constant that gets released if nothing retains it.